# For which values of $p$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n{{\ln^pn}\over{n}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find for which values of $p$ the following series converges:  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n{{\ln^pn}\over{n}}$$

I found that for any value of $p$, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} {\ln^p n\over n}=0$$

Now I have to prove that $f:x \longmapsto{\ln^p x\over x}$   is a decreasing function to apply the alternating series test.

Its derivative is $$f'(x)={{p\over x}\ln^{p-1}x \times x-\ln^px\over x^2}={\ln^{p-1}x(p-\ln x)\over x^2}$$ Thus, for $x>1,$ $$f'(x)\leq0\Leftrightarrow p\leq \ln{x}$$

And then I'm not quite sure whether it means something. Is my reasoning correct in the first place?

Comment: You are moving in the right direction. You only need to show the terms are eventually decreasing. This means the terms decrease as soon as $p\le \ln n.$ (PS: $\ln(n)^p$ isn't the right notation. )

Comment: I see, so can I say that f is decreasing for any value of $p$ because $\ln x$ eventually becomes greater than $p$ at a certain point?

Answer (score 1):

So, if $n>\mathrm e^p$, the general term $\:\dfrac{\ln^pn}n\:$ *decreases* to $0$, and *Leibniz' criterion* applies, since convergence of a series  isn't modified if you change a finite number of terms.